# Guard and Spork are slowing rspec down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, guard, spork

I am building a rails app with TDD, using Guard and Spork. I have recently noticed that guard and spork are in fact consistently and significantly slowing rspec down instead of speeding it up, which makes no sense to me.

For example:

running rspec spec **without** guard and spork my suite runs in **5.71 seconds**

Turning **guard and spork on** runs the suite in **7.67 seconds** which is a **35%** time increase.

You may think that this is only the first time that guard and spork are being launched but this is not the case. With **guard and spork in the background** rspec consistently run in **6.89-7 seconds** which is still considerably slower than without it

I'm on a nice and fast linux box, using Rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0p247.
If you need any other info about my config or would like to help feel free to browse the project: https://github.com/assafshomer/shout

Now this makes no sense to me. I thought running spork will at least save the rails environment load time. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing --drb? `rspec . --drb`?

Comment: If you're running via guard (as in running specs from within guard console) then I have no idea why because guard is configured to use `--drb` flag automatically.

Comment: Damien, as you mentioned --drb is being passed automatically.
Here is what the console shows:

[1] guard(main)> 

11:17:04 - INFO - Run all

11:17:04 - INFO - Running all specs

Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "/home/assaf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/guard-rspec-2.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec"]...